# is it correct to use Activity paramActivity rather than Context context in my adapter

Tags: java, android

Hi am new to android and I have a question that may seem very simple but I am just trying to understand this code I found on the net

by using Activity paramActivity is it referring to the Activity context and why not using activity .this?

Is it possible for the constractor adaptor to contain values that are missing from the super adapter?

```
public class myAdapter
      extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {
      private final Activity context;
      private final String[] subtitleId;
      private final String[] titleId;

      public myAdapter(Activity paramActivity, String[] paramArrayOfString1, 
      String[] paramArrayOfString2)
      {
        super(paramActivity, 2745458745 , paramArrayOfString1);
        this.context = paramActivity;
        this.titleId = paramArrayOfString1;
        this.subtitleId = paramArrayOfString2;
      }
   public View getView(int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup 
   paramViewGroup)
  {
    View localView = this.context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(2745458745, 
    null, true);
    TextView localTextView1 = (TextView)localView.findViewById(2131296514);
    TextView localTextView2 = (TextView)localView.findViewById(2131296502);
    localTextView1.setText(this.titleId[paramInt]);
    localTextView2.setText(this.subtitleId[paramInt]);
    return localView;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> by using Activity paramActivity is it referring to the Activity context

Assuming that you are passing Activity that extends `AppCompatActivity` as parameter...

YourActivity extends `AppCompatActivity` that extends `FragmentActivity` which extends `BaseFragmentActivityApi16` and it extends `BaseFragmentActivityApi14` that extends `SupportActivity` which extends `Activity` which extends `ContextThemeWrapper` that extends `ContextWrapper` that which you will find extends `Context`.

This might sound like too much to take, but don't worry, what you have to take from here is that you can cast your `Activity` as a `Context`.

> why not using activity.this

To use Activity.this you have to have that Activity's class enclosing the field from where you are writing that statement as `this` refers to current instance of the class.

For clearer understating you should look up for `this` keyword in Java.

Comment: when i checked the code the adapter extends  ArrayAdapter<String> but there library import ,import android.app.Activity; am i right to say that the Activity parameter passed in the constractor reffers to android.app.Activity wich extends all the way to the Context

Comment: also not sure why in the super constractor there is one value different from the adapter class constractor are they not supposed to be the same?

Comment: @Sven.hig I think you are really misunderstanding the Adapter importing `android.app.activity`. Adapter is importing it, because you have Activity data type in your parameter (remember you initial question?). If you have Android studio try removing that import and you will see Activity keyword will become red and show you balloon to press alt + enter to import Activity class. Hope I was able to answer all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `Activity.this` because adapter needs context and the super constructor example posted below.

In ArrayAdapter You need to define arrayList as well as textview for displaying arrylist item.

```
  public ArrayPopupAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> mItems) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, mItems);
    this.mContext = context;
}
```

Comment: do you have any idea why in the super constractor there is one value different from the adapter class constractor are they not supposed to be the same?

Comment: Normally they supposed to be same but i don't know from where did you get this code and what are requirements to do so, but from seeing this i can say that they probably use different textview for adapter that is not include in constructor.

Comment: I think you meant by the textview the paramArrayOfString2, the  2745458745 is the resource id I thought it should be in the adaptor constractor as well as the super constractor i put the rest of the code if that helps